# $\operatorname{Cov}(\mathbf{x,y})+\operatorname{Cov}(\mathbf{y,x})=2\operatorname{Cov}(\mathbf{x,y})$

Tags: covariance

Let **x** and **y** be random vectors of the same dimension. The covariance of **x**+**y** is:$\DeclareMathOperator{\Cov}{Cov}$
$$\Cov(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y})= \Cov(\mathbf{x})+\Cov(\mathbf{y})+ \Cov(\mathbf{x,y})+\Cov(\mathbf{y,x})$$
Is it correct $\;\Cov(\mathbf{x,y})+\Cov(\mathbf{y,x}) =2\Cov(\mathbf{x,y})$?

Comment: What do you mean when you apply covariance to a single argument?  Covariance is a measure of the joint variability of **two** random variables.

Comment: When you take the variance of all single argument functions in the first line, your conclusion is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the definition, note that if $X$ and $Y$ be random vector, so $$Cov(X,Y)=\mathbb{E}(XY)-\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)$$where $\mathbb{E}(X)$ denote *expected value* of $X$. Can you continue from here?